# PHP crypt and salt - more clarification please

Tags: php, encryption, salt, mcrypt

I was here yesterday and got some really great answers. I took what I got and put together, what I think will be a fairly secure algorithm. I'm having a problem using blowfish with a for loop that generates the salt.

I'm using base64 characters and a for loop to get a random string. I want to take this generated string and insert it into the crypt function as the salt.

Because the documentation about blowfish is so sparse and the PHP docs don't really even mention it, I'm sort of stabbing in the dark here.

The really strange thing is if you run this code the way it is now, it will **not** fail. Remove **either** the '$2a$07$' from above the for loop **or** from the crypt function and it will **intermittently** return an encrypted string. My understanding of blowfish is that the encrypted string **must** begin with '$2a$07$' and end in "$' hence the concatenation in the crypt function. I really don't need the beginning string above the for loop and just wanted to get rid of it.

I also would like clarification about the best practice on storing the random salt, either in the database **or** by storing the output of the crypt function in the database?

Yesterday, there was no real code being thrown around, just discussion. I'd like to put some code together today and have something that is fairly secure in place. If anyone can come up with a better algorithm, I'm always open.

```
$base64 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/';
$salt = '$2a$07$';

for($i=0; $i<60; $i++)
{
    $salt .= $base64[rand(0,63)];
}

return crypt('password', '$2a$07$'.$salt.'$');
```

Comment: You're prepending `$2a$07$` twice to the salt value, is that intentional?

Comment: Yes. That is why I am posting. If you remove either one of those strings, the crypt function randomly will return an encrypted string. I'd like to remove the string from above the for loop and keep the string in the crypt function. When I remove it, the crypt function fails.

Comment: If you run this code the way it is, it will not fail. Remove either one of these $2a$07$ strings and it fails.

Comment: A quick check of the documentation says that the salt for blowfish must be 16 characters long; have you tried reducing the length of salt?

Comment: Yes. I went all the way down to 9 characters. In fact, I tried everything from as little as 2 all the way up. It's weird.

Comment: I also found this from a contributing user on the PHP site. "Blowfish doesn't use a sixteen character salt, it uses sixteen *bytes* of salt."

Comment: @timmay: a character is typically 1 byte on most systems. Note the comment states 22 base 64 chars - which is 16 ascii chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `crypt()` dislikes `+` char in the salt, and a lot of other special chars as well (`*`, `%` etc). If you filter them out it should work on every try (and no need repeating the salt id string).

Comment: i'm not sure why it works if you append the salt id twice, but maybe one of the $ in the second id makes it stop parsing the salt after that or similar. >_<

Comment: Wow kb, you're right. It hasn't failed once. I just removed the last two characters in the base64 string.

Comment: The valid characters for the salt are `[a-zA-Z0-9./]` - really, this should be stated in the PHP documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is practically ancient history now, but for the benefit of anyone who finds it by searching google, there is a pretty detailed description of how the bcrypt/EksBlowfish salts work in the answer to this question:

[Why does crypt/blowfish generate the same hash with two different salts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225720/why-does-crypt-blowfish-generate-the-same-hash-with-two-different-salts)

The short answer is, as caf said, it uses a base64 alphabet composed of `[a-zA-Z0-9./]`, with `$` as the null (NOT 0) terminating/padding character.  If you use any characters outside of that range, or a `$` too early, it will either error out or not interpret the entirety of the salt.