# Can someone clarify how the PHP function crypt() works?

Tags: php, password-encryption

From my understanding crypt(string, salt), takes the salt, tacks it onto the front of the encrypted version of the string parameter.

```
$pw = "secret";
$format_and_salt = $2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NT;
$hash = crypt($pw, $format_and_salt);
```

$hash gets stored to the database column `hashed_password` as `$2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NOfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqm`

or broken down:

first part is $format_and_salt: `$2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1N (sans the 'T')`

+

second part is the encrypted $pw: `OfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqm`

If I then use crypt again to validate a password that a user submits to $_POST against the stored hashed_password in the database, the output for both cases doesn't seem to reflect the logic I described above.  So I'm missing something.

So then:

`$existing_hash = $admin['hashed_password']` ($admin being an array ultimately derived from a query).

and

`crypt($pw, $existing_hash)` returns `$2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NOfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqm`

which is identical to `$hash` above.  This works to validate or invalidate the users submission to $_POST, but as mentioned, if I follow the logic for the first crypt() above, I would expect:

first part is $existing_hash: `$2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NOfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqm`

+

second part is the encrypted $pw:  `OfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqm`

which I'd expect to combine as:
`$2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NOfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqmOfGsQUgIu7ezETpe.uHjGqbmdrw2.vqm`

Can someone explain why the original crypt and the crypt just above that was used to validate the first one both have the same output?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're using Blowfish encryption - only the first 22 characters of the salt are used. This is one of the  benefits of using blowfish.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php):

> Blowfish hashing with a salt as follows: "$2a$", "$2x$" or "$2y$", a two digit cost parameter, "$", and 22 characters from the alphabet "./0-9A-Za-z".

This means that the salt from $existing_hash ends up being `$2y$10$MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1N` - exactly the same as previously.

Comment: Actually it's BCrypt hashing (Blowfish encryption is another thing), otherwise that's the correct answer. The crypt function only extracts the salt from the existing hash, and uses it to generate a comparable hash with the entered password.

Comment: `MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1N` is only 21 characters. Does the `$2y$10$` count as the 22nd character?

Comment: @martinstoeckli in the PHP implementation it's referred to as blowfish. Perhaps I should have said 'You're using the blowfish option'.

Comment: @mwotton - Ah well, Blowfish is an encryption algorithm (two-way), while BCrypt is derrived from Blowfish but is a hash algorithm (one-way). It is indeed a bit confusing.

Comment: @dbconfession I wondered about that too - perhaps the `$` is being counted even though the manual indicates it should be 22 characters AFTER the `$` symbol.

Comment: @dbconfession - BCrypt expects a salt of 22 characters, but it uses only 126 of the 128 bits. Thus your salt `MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NT` can become `MWRmZTkwMTc5ZGJjZDI1NO`. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20927202/575765) for more details.